# 'super' object not calling __getattr__

Tags: python, getattr

I have one object wrapped inside another.
The "Wrapper" accesses the attributes from the "Wrapped" object by overriding `__getattr__`.
This works well until I need to override an atribute on a sub class, and then access the attribute from the base class using `super()`.

I can still access the attribute directly from `__getattr__` but why does `super()` not work?

```
class Wrapped(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def hello_world(self):
        print 'hello world', self.value

class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.wrapped_obj = obj

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self.__dict__:
            return getattr(self, name)
        else:
            return getattr(self.wrapped_obj, name)

class Subclass(Wrapper):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        super(Subclass, self).__init__(obj)

    def hello_world(self):
        # this works
        func = super(Subclass, self).__getattr__('hello_world')()
        # this doesn't
        super(Subclass, self).hello_world()

a = Wrapped(2)
b = Subclass(a)
b.hello_world()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm reading the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) correctly, but this seems to be a feature: *Note that `super()` is implemented as part of the binding process for explicit dotted attribute lookups such as `super().__getitem__(name)`. It does so by implementing its own `__getattribute__()` method for searching classes in a predictable order that supports cooperative multiple inheritance. Accordingly, `super()` is undefined for implicit lookups using statements or operators such as `super()[name]`.*

Comment: On a side note, your `__getattr__`'s code inside `if name in self.__dict__:` will never be reached: `__getattr__` is not called if a name is defined in the instance's `__dict__`. This is a potential source of hard to find bugs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[According to this,](https://lists.archive.carbon60.com/python/python/159397?do=post_view_threaded) super does not allow implicit calls of "hook" functions such as `__getattr__`. I'm not sure why it is implemented this way (there's probably a good reason and things are already confusing enough since the super object has custom `__getattribute__` and `__get__` methods as it is), but it seems like it's just the way things are.

Edit: [This post appears to clear things up a little.](https://web.archive.org/web/20151123075156/http://www.gossamer-threads.com:80/lists/python/python/159393) It looks like the problem is the extra layer of indirection caused by `__getattribute__` is ignored when calling functions implicitly. Doing `foo.x` is equivalent to

```
foo.__getattr__(x)
```

(Assuming no `__getattribute__` method is defined and x is not in `foo.__dict__`)
However, it is NOT equivalent to

```
foo.__getattribute__('__getattr__')(x)
```

Since super returns a proxy object, it has an extra layer of indirection which causes things to fail.

P.S. The `self.__dict__` check in your `__getattr__` function is completely unnecessary. `__getattr__` is only called if the attribute doesn't already exist in your dict. (Use `__getattribute__` if you want it to always be called, but then you have to be very careful, because even something simple like `if name in self.__dict__` will cause infinite recursion.

Comment: This does look like a bug - at least it does not adhere to the Least Surprise Principle ;)

Comment: @Tony on the other hand, there is a strong case for limiting indirection of magic methods. Not only for performance, but because otherwise you'd get into an infinite loop in some cases (such as having to call `__getattribute__` to find the `__getattribute__` method!)