# python: cooperative supercall of __getattr__

Tags: python, super, getattr, getattribute

I'm working with somethign similar to this code:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return lambda:'1'

class SubClass(BaseClass):
    def foo(self):
        suffix = '2'
        return super(SubClass, self).foo() + suffix

class SubClass2(SubClass):
    def foo(self):
        suffix = '3'
        return super(SubClass2, self).foo() + suffix

o = SubClass2()
print o.foo()
```

I'd expect to see output of '123', but I instead I get an error `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'foo'`. Python isn't even attempting to use the base class's `__getattr__`.

Without modifying the base class, and keeping the two super calls similar, I'm not able to get the output I want. Is there any cooperative supercall pattern that will work for me here?

I understand that super() overrides **getattr** in some way to do what it needs to do, but I'm asking if there's any reasonable workaround that allows a subclass's `__getattr__` to be called when appropriate.

Comment: possible duplicate of ['super' object not calling \_\_getattr\_\_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047847/super-object-not-calling-getattr)

Comment: @eevee The proposed duplicate asks "why does super not work?" whereas I'm asking for a procedure that does work, given that super won't work.

Answer (score 5):

Ah, this is a great question!

In short, what's going on here is that the CPython internals occasionally take
shortcuts when they are doing attribute lookups, and this kind of surprising
behaviour is one of the consequences (another one being improved performance).

To understand exactly what's happening in this situation, we need to venture
into the definition of `super`:
http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c24941251473/Objects/typeobject.c#l6689

Notice specifically that it doesn't define
[`tp_getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#PyTypeObject.tp_getattr)
(aka `__getattr__`), but does define [`tp_getattro`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#PyTypeObject.tp_getattro) (aka `__getattribute__`):

```
PyTypeObject PySuper_Type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)
    "super",                                    /* tp_name */
    ...
    0,                                          /* tp_getattr */
    ...
    super_getattro,                             /* tp_getattro */
    ...
};
```

(recall that `__getattribute__` is called *every time* an attribute is
requested, as opposed to `__getattr__`, which is only called if the attribute
doesn't exist on the object (roughly: if the attribute isn't in the object's
`__dict__`)).

Next, looking into the definition of
[`super_getattro`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c24941251473/Objects/typeobject.c#l6475)
(aka `super.__getattribute__`), we can see the implementation is
*approximately*:

```
class super(object):
    def __init__(self, obj_type, obj):
        self.obj_type = obj_type
        self.obj = obj

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        i = self.obj_type.__mro__.find(self.obj_type)
        i += 1
        while i < len(obj_type.__mro__):
            cur_type = self.obj_type.__mro__[i]
            cur_dict = cur_type.__dict___
            res = cur_dict.get(attr)
            if res is not None:
                return res
            i += 1
        return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
```

Which makes it obvious why `super` doesn't play well with `__getattr__` —
`super` is only checking for attributes in the parent class' `__dict__`!

Fun aside: it seems like `pypy` (as of 2.1.0) behaves the same way:

```
$ pypy super.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app_main.py", line 72, in run_toplevel
  File "super.py", line 16, in <module>
    print o.foo()
  File "super.py", line 13, in foo
    return super(SubClass2, self).foo() + suffix
  File "super.py", line 8, in foo
    return super(SubClass, self).foo() + suffix
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work correctly. I don't currently see why the standard super class doesn't do this.

```
class super2(super):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self.__self__.__getattr__(attr)

class BaseClass(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return lambda:'1'

class SubClass(BaseClass):
    def foo(self):
        suffix = '2'
        return super2(SubClass, self).foo() + suffix

class SubClass2(SubClass):
    def foo(self):
        suffix = '3'
        return super2(SubClass2, self).foo() + suffix

o = SubClass2()
print o.foo()
```

Comment: note that `object.__getattr__` does not exist, so this would break the already-fragile case of diamond inheritance from `object`.  this may also allow metaclass methods to interfere with method resolution in some cases.

Comment: Should check `hasattr(self.__self__, '__getattr__')` on line 3 and raise an exception if `__getattr__` is not provided.