About inheritance in python, why don't people write 'self' in child class?
Here is an example.
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def get_name(self):
        print('My name is %s.'%self.name)
    
    def get_age(self):
        print('I am %d years old.'%self.age)

class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, age, GPA):
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.GPA = GPA

    def get_GPA(self):
        print('My grade is %f.'%self.GPA)

Here comes up my curiosity.
When I create Student class,
isn't it allowed to code super().__init__(self, name, age)?
If not, what is the precise reason why 'self' should not added to super().__init__(name, age)?

Do you understand what super() is returning?  In this case, that is taking the place of the "self". I'm not sure what level to target the answer at, because it can end up in a lot of advanced topics to explain fully (multiple inheritance MRO, descriptor protocol, data model...)

The simple answer is that super() handles this automatically.

@Barmar I don't think super() actually handles it at all.  Just normal descriptor binding stuff.

I'm not sure why you're being downvoted. It's a good question. I had a similar question 10 years ago - https://stackoverflow.com/q/25924548/674039

@wim In Python 2 you had to write super(Person, self). Python 3 allows you to omit these arguments and it fills them in automatically by introspecting the stack.

@Barmar Not a dupe. Not of that target, anyway.

Maybe the best answer is an analogy: if you were to call the get_PGA method
of a student instance, you wouldn't do it like:
student.get_PGA(student)

Instead you would just do student.get_PGA(). The "self" would be passed in implicitly.
Similarly, if you were calling it from within another method you wouldn't call it like:
class Student(Person):

    def foo(self):
        pga = self.get_PGA(self)


You would just use self.get_PGA() instead.
When calling a method, the first positional argument is implicit.  It's the same story with Student.__init__, which is just a method, here the proxy instance returned by super() is passed in as the "self" implicitly.

I don't see how this helps, because you don't say self.super().

Ao how does it know to bind the superclass method to self?

That's the implicit __class__ cell. It's sort of black magic CPython stuff, and I decided it's irrelevant to the actual question to go into it. The important point here is that super() takes the place of self, not about how super itself works.

__class__ is not the same as self. It seems that there's two different forms of black magic.

@Barmar Finding the self is simple for super(), it's in scope already as a local variable. The mechanism is naive and if you reassign self = 1 or do del self before using zero-arg super() Python will get confused.

You can't just look for the name self in the local variables, since that's just a naming convention and not required by the language. As the question I linked to said, it actually uses stack introspection.

@Barmar First positional argument, whatever it is named. The point is the same.

It's very different: One is stack black magic, the other is variable scope black magic.
