# What is the solution to this problem AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Tags: python, function, class, kivy, init

I have this code

```
class ScreenMain(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwarge):
        super(ScreenMain,self).__init__(**kwarge)
        self.ids.input2.text=get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(self.ids.input2.text))
```

When I run the code it gives me this error

AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'

And I tried a lot to solve this problem, even with the addition of parentheses to Screen Mine, so that the code looks like this:

```
super(ScreenMain(),self).__init__(**kwarge)
```

This error occurs:

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

I did not find a solution in either case

Is there a solution or is this becoming something impossible and difficult

Comment: The `RecursionError` occurs because `ScreenMain()` calls `__init__()`, which in turn calls `ScreenMain()`, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['super' object has no attribute '\_\_getattr\_\_' in python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28861064/super-object-has-no-attribute-getattr-in-python3)

Comment: Can you explain more

Comment: Please post a [mcve].