# Calling overloaded method using super() yields AttributeError

Tags: python, oop

I have a class definition like

```
from tinydb import TinyDB

class DB(TinyDB):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        return super(DB, self).__init__(filename)

    def exists(self, url):
        return bool(self.search(Entry.url == url))

    def insert(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(self) > 100:
            self.purge_tables()

        return super(DB, self).insert(*args, **kwargs)
```

where [`TinyDB` is from the `tinydb` package](https://github.com/msiemens/tinydb/blob/master/tinydb/database.py#L57).

When I now try to run

```
database = db.DB('test.json')
database.insert({'title': 'Hello', 'url': 'foo'})
```

I get an error message

```
return super(DB, self).insert(*args, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

Whereas when I do

```
from tinydb import TinyDB

database2 = TinyDB('test.json')
database2.insert({'title': 'Hello', 'url': 'foo'})
```

`insert()` is there, [provided by](https://github.com/msiemens/tinydb/blob/master/tinydb/database.py#L164)

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    """
    Forward all unknown attribute calls to the underlying standard table.
    """
    return getattr(self._table, name)
```

There seem to be some intricacies with this way of making attributes from one attribute within your class accessible to the outside.

Comment: The superclass doesn't appear to define an `insert` method, where were you expecting it to come from?

Comment: See my edit. The baseclass `TinyDB` seems to have an `insert()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last example works because of the `__getattr__` method defined on `TinyDB`:

```
class TinyDB(object):
    # [....]
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """
        Forward all unknown attribute calls to the underlying standard table.
        """
        return getattr(self._table, name)
```

and indeed, the `insert` method is defined on `Table`. You can fix your example by using:

```
def insert(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if len(self) > 100:
        self.purge_tables()

    return self._table.insert(*args, **kwargs)
```

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12048087/517560) has more explanation on why it does not work like you expect.