# Initiaized class member in pytorch module

Tags: python, pytorch

When declaring a model in pytorch, having a model class member variable declared and initialized mysteriously prevents it from being populated in the constructor. Is this expected? If so, why?

Testing code below, with example models with a `component` member variable.
The initialization value of the component (e.g. `None`, a number or a Tensor) does not change the behaviour.

```py
import torch

class Lin1(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Lin1, self).__init__()
        self.component = torch.nn.Linear(100,200)

class Lin2(torch.nn.Module):
    component = None
    def __init__(self):
        super(Lin2, self).__init__()
        self.component = torch.nn.Linear(100,200)

# instantiate and check member component
for cl in [Lin1, Lin2]:
    model = cl()
    print("\nModel:", cl)
    print("Component:", model.component)
    print("It's None?: ", model.component is None)
```

```
Model: <class '__main__.Lin1'>
Component: Linear(in_features=100, out_features=200, bias=True)
It's None?:  False

Model: <class '__main__.Lin2'>
Component: None
It's None?:  True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `nn.Module` overwrites `__getattr__`, and it would only work as you expect if `component` was not in `Lin2.__dict__` (nor in `Lin2().__dict__`). Since `component` is a class attribute, it is in `Lin2.__dict__` and will be returned as it should.

When you write `self.x = nn.Linear(...)` or any other `nn.Module` (or even `nn.Buffer` or `nn.Parameter`), `x` is actually registered in a dictionary called `_modules` (or `_buffers`, etc.) In this way, when you ask for `self.component`, if `component` is already in the `__dict__` of the class or the instance, Python will not call the custom `nn.Module`'s `__getattr__()`.

You can check the source-code of `__getattr__` from `nn.Module` [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/16c72a5a6b7085a9651e7bef7e98c80b2d5547e9/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L782-L796). A similar discussion was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047847/super-object-not-calling-getattr). There was also a [discussion](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/16823) about changing from `__getattr__` to `__getattribute__` in PyTorch, but as of now, this is a [wontfix issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/13981#issuecomment-461861947).